# Webstorm on Ubuntu: npm install issues and permissions on folders

Tags: ubuntu, npm, installation, bower, webstorm

I get the following error when try updating bower to current version:

```
/usr/bin/npm install bower@1.6.5

Exit code: 243

Standard error:
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-51-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bower@1.6.5"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/bower
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rmdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/bower']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/bower' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/bower']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/bower' }
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-51-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bower@1.6.5"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.70f6a7ba731584486ee86965f4d50da8
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.70f6a7ba731584486ee86965f4d50da8'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.70f6a7ba731584486ee86965f4d50da8']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.70f6a7ba731584486ee86965f4d50da8' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/lib/node_modules/npm-debug.log
```

How to make Webstorm run npm with sudo? This problem is both in Webstorm 10 and in the new WS 11. Netbeans meanwhile works absolutely perfectly without any troubles.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/lib/node_modules
```

Try this. Directory removing error will be resolved.

```
Solution Revised As Per the Requirement 1:
```

always work in sudo mode

before Work Always do **sudo -i** 
if you are the **super user** then only you will be able to do all the things in system

```
Solution Revised As Per the Requirement 2:
```

Always Start your webstorm by command **sudo /bin/sh /home/****/Desktop/WebStorm-139.1112/bin/webstorm.sh**

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I thought there can be any other solution because it seems not too good to make somthing inside /usr/lib write enabled to all...

Comment: It anyway solved the problem, all updates work correctly

Comment: Jetbrains should really just prompt for sudo permission in such a case. Starting the IDE with sudo brings several other issues...